# How Redirect to 3rd party payment gateway in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, redirect-url

In Magento 1 we define the **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl** in the model which extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and redirect to a particular controller after checkout submit.

Then from the controller we call `$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('someblock')->toHtml())` and inside the block we create a form with post data and redirect to a 3rd party payment gateway.

In Magento 2 I heard that **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl** is not available and I'm unable to understand how it is handled.

Can someone please guide me to achieve the above scenario in Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the placeOrder function in your method-render JS function.

```
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Yuansfer_Yuansfer/payment/form'
        },
        getCode: function () {
            return 'yuansfer_alipay';
        },
        isActive: function () {
            return true;
        },
        getMediaUrl: function () {
            return mediaUrl;
        },
        placeOrder: function (data, event) {
            if(event) {
              event.preventDefault();  
            }

            var self = this,
                placeOrder,
                emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';

            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }

            if (emailValidationResult && this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);

                var setPaymentInfo = setPaymentInformationAction(this.messageContainer, self.getData());
                    $.when(setPaymentInfo).fail(function () {
                        self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                    }).done(
                            this.afterPlaceOrder.bind(this)
                        );
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        selectPaymentMethod: function () {
            selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
            checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);
            return true;
        },
        afterPlaceOrder: function () {
            window.location.replace(url.build('module_name/controller/action/'));
        }
    });
}
);
```

The key is here `afterPlaceOrder` function.
You should redirect to your save action here.